# No output generated while using python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pattern-matching, default-value, string-matching

I'm trying to match two txt files and then saving the index of matched locations in a python dictionary called tmp.

Now I'm trying to print the content between the start index and end index based on the dictionary..

Some Key/values were missing in the dictionary so I used default values
But now When I try to print the required result using line[s:e] it is giving me a blank output

while default values are there..

Hope i'm able to explain myself..

Please look at the code..

code type = Python

```
 import re

 content_file = open('/Users/ashishyadav/Downloads/pdfminer-20110515/samples/te.txt',"r")
 product_file = open('/Users/ashishyadav/Desktop/AQ/te.txt',"r")
 output = open("output.txt" , "w")
 line = content_file.read().lower().strip()
 tmp = {}
 default=99
 for k in tmp:
    tmp[k]=default

 prev=''
 for prod in product_file:
   for match in re.finditer(prod.lower().strip(), line):
           prod = prod.replace("\r","")
           prod = prod.replace("\n","")
           if(prev!=''):
                   tmp[prev,'end_index']=match.start()
           tmp[prod,'start_index']=match.start()
           s=match.start()
           e=match.end()
           prev=prod
           #print >>output, match.group(),"\t",
           #print >>output, '%d:%d' % ( s, e),"\n",        
           #print >>output, tmp,"\n"
```

^^this is saving the index locations to a dictionary called tmp

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 tmp = defaultdict(lambda:99,tmp)
 print tmp
 print tmp[('Steakhouse Filet Salad', 'end_index')]
 print tmp[('FRIED PICKLES', 'end_index')]
 print tmp[('TEXAS T-BONE', 'end_index')]
```

default value of Steakhouse Filet Salad is now 99 cause it's not in the dictionary

```
 for prod in product_file:
    for match in re.finditer(prod.lower().strip(), line):
        prod = prod.replace("\r","")
            prod = prod.replace("\n","")
            print line[s:tmp[(prod,'end_index')]]
```

this print line[s:tmp[(prod,'end_index')]]
was giving a keyerror before but as now the default value is 99 it should take it and give me some result but no output is generated.

Comment: Where does `s` come from to the last bit of code?

Comment: Never mind got it..I had to reload the two files again after the loop and then use line[tmp[prod,'start_index']:tmp[(prod,'end_index')]] and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

What does `s` mean in `line[s:tmp[(prod,'end_index')]]`?  Trace down its definition and take into accout the next Python behaviour:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> print l[10:1]
[]
```

Now you should be able to find your bug.

Comment: Never mind got it..I had to reload the two files again after the loop and then use line[tmp[prod,'start_index']:tmp[(prod,'end_index')]]  and it worked just fine...